# Forgot your Passowrd Email Authentication Required

Tags: magento-1.9, email, password-recovery

I am using magento 1.9.2.3 version. Is it possible can we make a email address authentication in Forgot Your Password Page.

Currently some one enter the wrong email address and system send an email. My client required if someone enter the email address for password reset first system check the email exist or not. If email exist than send email if not than error message your email is not registered.

Answer (score 1):

This Question asked and answerd At Stackoverflow Please check Below Url for answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274497/how-to-override-forgot-password-message-in-magento